# How can I re-arrange array indexes in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

At first: Apologies for my not-so-good English, I'm a 17-year old German ;-)

I do my apprentice as a web-developer and just stumbled upon a problem:

I need to re-arrange the indexes of an array. The array is basically like that:

```
@array = ( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
```

But: it changes dynamically, so it doesnt always have 3 elements, but something over 20. Now, what I need to do is to get it to:

```
@array = ( 'c', 'a', 'b' );
```

So, I thought I just needed to do something like that (in a for-loop that loops once for every element in the array and increments $counter)

```
my $last = $array[$#array];
for($#array)
{
    $array[$counter] = $array[$counter + 1];
    unshift(@array, $last);
    pop(@array);
    $counter++;
}
```

I thought it would do this:

For each element in array (lets say, we are at element 0): Set element index = element index + 1; then add the last array to the beginning and remove the now "real" last array (which is just a duplicate of the beginning now). Then adding 1 to the counter and redo that for the array. But it doesnt really do what I want.

Well, that was my "newbie" try, so again, thats what I just need:

I need to "move" all the elements indexes of the array +1 and cut off the last one then to be at the beginning. The maybe more complicated thing is, that the arrays length is just variable.

In another form: 
I need to turn

```
( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ... 'z');
```

to

```
( 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', ... 'y' );
```

Ive got no idea how to go on and I would appreciate any help.

Thanks :-)

**Already thanks for all your anwers! I forgot to say that I cant test it before monday, because Im not at work anymore and I dont have the source with me right now. But thanks, Im sure at least one of your solutions will work!**

Answer (score 7):

```
@array = { 'c', 'a', 'b' };
```

assigns a single element (a hash reference) to @array; I think you mean

```
@array = ( 'c', 'a', 'b' );
```

This for loop:

```
for ($#array)
```

only loops over the single value $#array (the last index of @array).

I'm guessing you meant something like:

```
for ( 0..$#array )
```

(loop over all the array indicies).

Inside your loop, you seem to be doing two different things; one rotating things with unshift/pop and one moving things with an assignment of elements.  Either approach would work (though in both you have errors), but both will not.

You can do:

```
my $last = $array[$#array];
for ( 0..$#array-1 ) {
    $array[$_+1] = $array[$_];
}
$array[0] = $last;
```

(no separate counter needed; the loop provides one)

or rotate by one (moving the first element to be last) the array one fewer times than there are elements:

```
for ( 1..$#array ) {
    push @array, shift @array;
}
```

or just do this to take the last element and make it first:

```
unshift @array, pop @array;
```

Or you can reassign all the elements at once, using a slice:

```
@array = @array[ $#array, 0..$#array-1 ];
```

or

```
@array[1..$#array, 0] = @array;
```

All of these produce the change you seem to want, but I don't feel confident you've explained clearly enough what that change is, given how complicated your attempt is compared to what would be needed to do what your example shows.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Thanks for that detailled explanation, but now, being in my company again and having it tested, I saw it was not what I needed. Its not your fault, though, its mine. What I needed was that: I have multiple strings (made by joining arrays) in a hash, and it may occur that I have (a, b, c) and (c, a, b). A hash filters it away if (a, b, c) is twice, of course. But not if the string is (c, a, b), but its the same data for me. I wanted to test if there are such multiple string that just have a different order, but well... its harder than I thought. Again: Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 4):

First, use round brackets for creating arrays in Perl:

```
@array = ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

If you want to move the last element to the beginning of the array, you can use:

```
unshift @array, pop @array;
```

Comment: Oh sorry. I just wrote that being at home out of my head. In original, I just use push to fill the array (which works perfectly like I want it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to take a look at List::Util, it's got a shuffle method that literally shuffles list contents.